# How to save window.onunload data in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cookies, window.onunload

I'm saving the state of the page contents in cookies as shown below.
There is a basic user authentication on the web application and the user data are saved in a database. Can I save the unonload function in the same collection so that I can link the user to the unonload function?

```
window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookiestyle = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookiestyle ? cookiestyle : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);

  var cookietab = readCookie("tabs");
  tabs = cookietab ? JSON.parse(cookietab) : [];

  var cookiesound = readCookie("sound");
  audiolink = cookiesound ? cookiesound : 
  http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav';
  audio = new Audio(audiolink);
  var cookiemuted = readCookie("muted");
  audio.muted = cookiemuted ? JSON.parse(cookiemuted) : false;
  var mutebuttontext = audio.muted ? "Mute sound - Yes" : "Mute sound - No";
  $("#mutefxn").text(mutebuttontext);


  var cookieshake = readCookie("shake");
  stylesheet.disabled = cookieshake ? JSON.parse(cookieshake) : false;
  var shakebuttontext = stylesheet.disabled ? "Shake - No" : "Shake - Yes";
  $("#shake").text(shakebuttontext);


  var cookiefontsize = readCookie("fontsize");
  document.body.style.fontSize = cookiefontsize ? cookiefontsize : "1.0em";

  for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var deviceName = tabs[i];
    var unspacedDeviceName = deviceName.replace(/\s/g, '');
    $(".components").append("<li><a  onclick=\"playSound()\" class=\"tabtext\" href=\"/device?selected=" + deviceName + "\" id=\"#tabname" + unspacedDeviceName + "\">" + deviceName + "</a></li>");
  }
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
  document.cookie = "tabs=" + JSON.stringify(tabs) + "";
  document.cookie = "sound=" + audiolink + "";
  document.cookie = "fontsize=" + document.body.style.fontSize + "";
  document.cookie = "muted=" + audio.muted + "";
  document.cookie = "shake=" + stylesheet.disabled + ""; 

}
```

Comment: There is really no way to guarantee that calls made with window unload will make it to the server.

Comment: but he's not sending anything to the server in onunload - if you want to send something (small) to the server onunload https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon